# How do I enter a plus sign ASP.NET Ajax HTMLEditor

Tags: .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax, html-editor

I am using Microsofts ASP.NET Ajax HTML editor found here http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/HTMLEditor/HTMLEditor.aspx.

When I enter a plus sign '+' into the editor it always gets stripped out and replaced with a space.  I even tried using `&#43;` but that failed to work.  Is some way to enter a plus sign into the editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing it with `&#43;` (which is the HTML alternative for the plus sign) in the source code view.

And report it to the developers of the ASP.Net Ajax HTML editor, because this sounds like a very annoying bug.

Comment: Where do I report bugs?  I tried to use the HTML alternative and that doesn't work.  I forgot to codify my + int he question to show it